# Do I draw a line or rule on a paper?

Tags: word-choice

When I use a ruler and a pen, is it a line or a rule that I draw? What are the dimensions of the line/rule, length and width, or length and thickness?

Comment: I have never thought about the fact that it could be different in wordprocessing and "classroom" use. My application is indeed a word processor, so I will take 'rule' into account, but now I know that I am not wrong if I say "With this you draw a line from ...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a *line,* especially for a math problem. Dimensions are in inches or centimeters, according to the problem. Thicknesses are in fractions of an inch or in mm.

I have seen *rule* for word processing or typesetting. Dimensions are again in inches or centimeters, but thicknesses here are in fractions of points.

Answer (score 4):

Classically, (ie mathematically), you would rule a line, which has, of course, neither width nor thickness. (the apparent thickness being experimental error).

Comment: The line that is drawn in a real world on a real paper is a representation of a geometrical line (which has no thickness). So, there is no problem there.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others that what you draw with a ruler is a line. The OED gives *a straight line drawn on paper; specifically, one of the lines of a stave of music* as one of the definitions of *rule*, but states that such use  is now rare. I, too, recall that in geometrical terms, a line has length but no width.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the OED. Sometimes I forget about its existence.

Comment: @Patrick: I find it indispensable, but it requires a paid subscription.

Comment: In geometry, a line _segment_ has length. A line extends infinitely in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

In contemporary English, it's a line that you draw, and you'd measure its length and its thickness. Width would be for a two-dimensional figure, like a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Any line you draw on paper has three dimensions, length, width, and depth (or thickness).  One says, "I drew a line using a ruler," "I ruled a line using a straightedge," "I ruled a line with a pen and rule," *etc.*

In vulgar parlance some speak of line *thickness* when they mean *width*.  In logical terms, and in CAD programs, the measurable dimensions of a drawn line are length and width.  Width varies as the pen- or pencil-tip width varies.  Thickness is the depth of the line on the drawing surface, typically sub-micrometer, and varies with ink or pencil lead properties, drawing pressure, paper surface qualities, *etc.*